# Extract left and right limit from a Series of pandas Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I want to get interval margins of a column with pandas intervals and write them in columns 'left', 'right'. Iterrows does not work (documentation says it would not be use for writing data) and, anyway it would not be the better solution.

```
import pandas as pd

i1 = pd.Interval(left=85, right=94)
i2 = pd.Interval(left=95, right=104)
i3 = pd.Interval(left=105, right=114)
i4 = pd.Interval(left=115, right=124)
i5 = pd.Interval(left=125, right=134)
i6 = pd.Interval(left=135, right=144)
i7 = pd.Interval(left=145, right=154)
i8 = pd.Interval(left=155, right=164)
i9 = pd.Interval(left=165, right=174)

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "intervals":[i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9],
    "left"     :[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    "right"    :[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },
    index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
)

#this is not working (has no effect):
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row.intervals.left, row.intervals.right)
    row.left = row.intervals.left
    row.right = row.intervals.right
```

How can we do something like:

```
data['left']=data['intervals'].left

data['right']=data['intervals'].right
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create an [`pandas.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) from your intervals. You can then access the `.left` and `.right` attributes.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IntervalIndex([i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9])  
pd.DataFrame({'intervals': idx, 'left': idx.left, 'right': idx.right})

    intervals  left  right
0    (85, 94]    85     94
1   (95, 104]    95    104
2  (105, 114]   105    114
3  (115, 124]   115    124
4  (125, 134]   125    134
5  (135, 144]   135    144
6  (145, 154]   145    154
7  (155, 164]   155    164
8  (165, 174]   165    174
```

---

Another option is using `map` and `operator.attrgetter` (look ma, no `lambda`...):

```
from operator import attrgetter

df['left'] = df['intervals'].map(attrgetter('left'))
df['right'] = df['intervals'].map(attrgetter('right'))

df
    intervals left right
0    (85, 94]   85    94
1   (95, 104]   95   104
2  (105, 114]  105   114
3  (115, 124]  115   124
4  (125, 134]  125   134
5  (135, 144]  135   144
6  (145, 154]  145   154
7  (155, 164]  155   164
8  (165, 174]  165   174
```

Comment: extra kudos for the 'Look Ma' comment

Answer (score 5):

A [`pandas.arrays.IntervalArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html), is the preferred way for storing interval data in `Series`-like structures.

For @coldspeed's first example, `IntervalArray` is basically a drop in replacement:

```
In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '1.1.3'

In [3]: ia = pd.arrays.IntervalArray([i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9])

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'intervals': ia, 'left': ia.left, 'right': ia.right})

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
    intervals  left  right
0    (85, 94]    85     94
1   (95, 104]    95    104
2  (105, 114]   105    114
3  (115, 124]   115    124
4  (125, 134]   125    134
5  (135, 144]   135    144
6  (145, 154]   145    154
7  (155, 164]   155    164
8  (165, 174]   165    174
```

If you already have interval data in a `Series` or `DataFrame`, @coldspeed's second example becomes a bit more simple by accessing the `array` attribute:

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'intervals': ia})

In [7]: df['left'] = df['intervals'].array.left

In [8]: df['right'] = df['intervals'].array.right

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
    intervals  left  right
0    (85, 94]    85     94
1   (95, 104]    95    104
2  (105, 114]   105    114
3  (115, 124]   115    124
4  (125, 134]   125    134
5  (135, 144]   135    144
6  (145, 154]   145    154
7  (155, 164]   155    164
8  (165, 174]   165    174
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use apply() method:

```py
    data['left'] = data['intervals'].apply(lambda x: x.left)
    data['right'] = data['intervals'].apply(lambda x: x.right)
    data
```

```
    intervals      left     right
    0   (85, 94]     85      94
    1   (95, 104]    95     104
    ...
    8   (165, 174]  165     174
```

Comment: This does work, however, it's not vectorized as in [a1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53996040/7758804) and [a2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044765/7758804), so this will be much slower, by comparison.